# Display Suite fails!

Tags: display-suite, entities

**Hi!**
Again, I apologize for writing bad English.

Put into context my problem: when you install *Display Suite*, the *Select Layout* option appears in *Manage Display* within each type of content created. When selecting a layout we can have control over where and how to display the title field.

This worked fine until I installed a module called: [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group). After installing this module, I have experienced two problems with *Display Suite*. One is as follows:

I set my_content_type to show the title field in full-content view. But it never appears in the frontend.

I deleted the Drupal cache. I cleaned the Drupal database with [Optimize DB](https://www.drupal.org/project/optimizedb). I uninstalled the Field Group module. Nothing works.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: maybe css is hiding it? have u tried disabling all css and checking if the tittle is there?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I checked web page with Chrome's Devtools, and the title is not there.

But Display Suite has more problems. For instance, Display Suite allows us to add HTML and CSS classes to the fields. I set up the HTML and those classes, but never appear in the frontend. If I go back to the settings, I see Display Suite does not save my settings.

Display Suite fails horribly!  :(

Comment: Have you tried disabling and also uninstalling Display Suite (so its no longer in your database) Then enabling Display Suite again?

Comment: Does this happen to just 1 content type? or does it happen to all your content types? (Article, Basic Page)

Comment: OK. These problems happen everywhere. Now, I did a test at local, and Display Suite uninstalled. I'm not sure that the problem has disappeared. But suppose so. The problem with the uninstall module, all settings are lost: the HTML and CSS classes assigned to the fields by Display Suite, are lost.